# RTSP Stream in Google Web Toolkit Widget

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, gwt, rtsp

All,

I was wondering if it was possible to pull in a RTSP Stream into a Google Web Toolkit application. If anyone has done so I would greatly appreciate it if you would describe how you did it in GWT and what jars or other files you used.

Thanks,

MPH

Comment: I have the server for the rtsp server already set up for another project I am working on but I was wondering if it was possible to do it in GWT.